# Combining data frames that are named consecutively

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have 100 data frames called df1, df2, df3 ...... df100. How can I use the rbind function without typing the name of every single data frame?

Comment: See `help(do.call)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `paste0("df", 1:100)` to generate the vector of the dataframe names. Then `mget(paste0("df", 1:100))` gives the dataframes in a list. And you can use `do.call` to call `rbind` on this list; finally the command is:

```
do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("df", 1:100)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly.